# Jackson JSON Mixin deserialization - Array with different types

Tags: json, jackson, mixins, vk

I have JSON string that looks like

```
{"response":[125,{"id":219},{"id":212}]}
```

So as you can see "response" is an array consist of Number and 2 POJOs (id:Number).

Could you please give me some advice how to deserialize such strings using Jackson Mixins?
Assumption every entry has POJO's type does not work - Jackson throws an Exception because Number is not an instance of POJO's.
Actually it's possible to skip this nasty Number I need only List of POJOs.

**Test.java**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule("VKontakteModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null)) {
            @Override
            public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                context.setMixInAnnotations(VKontaktePost.class, VKontaktePostMixin.class);
                context.setMixInAnnotations(VKontaktePosts.class, VKontaktePostsMixin.class);
            }
        });
String str;
VKontaktePosts posts;
str = "{\"response\":[{\"id\":282},{\"id\":283}]}";
posts = objectMapper.readValue(deserStr, VKontaktePosts.class); //Works

str = "{\"response\":[125,{\"id\":282},{\"id\":283}]}";
posts = objectMapper.readValue(deserStr, VKontaktePosts.class); //Throws JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of VKontaktePost, problem: no suitable creator method found to deserialize from JSON Number
```

**VKontaktePosts.java**

```
public class VKontaktePosts implements Serializable {

    private final List<VKontaktePost> posts;

    public VKontaktePosts(List<VKontaktePost> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public List<VKontaktePost> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

}
```

**VKontaktePost.java**

```
public class VKontaktePost {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**VKontaktePostsMixin.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class VKontaktePostsMixin {

    @JsonCreator
    VKontaktePostsMixin(@JsonProperty("response") List<VKontaktePostMixin> posts) {
    }

    @JsonProperty("response")
    abstract List<VKontaktePostMixin> getPosts();

}
```

**VKontaktePostMixin.java**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class VKontaktePostMixin {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    abstract String getId();

}
```